# How do I get the IP of a server sending GET to my Node server running on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have a Node server that receives a GET request from an external source when they hit a certain url. "https://appname.herokuapp.com/example"

I want to make it to where only three specific IPs can hit that address and run the GET on my server.

```
app.get('/example', function (req,res) {
  console.log(req.connection.remoteAccess);
  if (req.connection.remoteAccess === 'X' || 'X' || 'X') {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

I'm trying this, but I get different IPs every time the external source hits that url. They said that the ones I'm getting look like internal network IPs, not external. Am I doing this wrong? I just want to get the IP of the server hitting the address and confirm it's one of the 3 verified ones.

EDIT: So there's no way to really securely confirm their IP? They're also sending a secret key within the req.query and it's over my https herokuapp url, so would this be a secure setup?

Comment: it's http. you'd only ever see the IP of whatever nat gateway/vpn server those requests are coming from. you'll never see the internal (private?) IPs of the devices. you COULD try checking things like the `http_x_forwarded_for` header and whatnot, but those are trivial to forge.

Answer (score 2):

As Marc said :

```
app.get('/example', function (req,res) {

  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']; 
  console.log(ip);

   if (ip === 'X' || 'X' || 'X') {
     //Do stuff
   }
}
```

But a much better place to do this would be at a firewall level.